# Video lazy loading skipping first video in every list

Tags: javascript

I'm using code found here:

https://codepad.co/snippet/CtLEQDKX

to lazy load the preview image for youtube videos within JComments. I have it working pretty good and looking like I want it to and it saves a massive amount of data from being unnecessarily downloaded, but for some reason the first video always gets skipped and left with no image and is unclickable. The rest work just as they're supposed to.

I have two sections the comments appear on, the other is a custom made profile page and is separate from JComments, and the same thing happens to the first video on the lists there as well. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Here is js being used on site:

```
<script>
( function() {

    var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );

    for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {

        var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/hqdefault.jpg";

        var image = new Image();
            image.src = source;
            image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
                youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
            }( i ) );

        youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

            var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
                iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
                iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
                iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );

            this.innerHTML = "";
            this.appendChild( iframe );
        } );    
    };

} )();
</script>
```

This is what the html looks like in custom bbcode, identifier is stripped out from pattern.

Pattern:

```
[youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={IDENTIFIER}[/youtube]
```

HTML:

```
<center>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="youtube" data-embed="{IDENTIFIER}">
<div class="play-button"></div>
</div></div></center>
```

and the profile str_replace is in 2 arrays, but looks like this

```
...., "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "[youtube]", "[/youtube]",.....

replaced by

...., "", '<center><div class="wrapper"><div class="youtube" data-embed="', '"><div class="play-button"></div></div></div></center>',.....
```

Extra info 
J! 3.9.1
PHP 7.1.25
OS Linux I
JComments 3.0.7

Comment: Can you help us to follow the process/breakdown by offering the data that is stored in your `youtube` variable?  Maybe there is some interference with your html? Please post your html so that we can have a look at the actual DOM being processed.  Furthermore, `source` is a single-use variable, so I recommend not declaring it (this won't fix the issue of course).

Comment: What is `youtube[i].dataset.embed` on the first iteration? Does `youtube[0]` have `dataset.embed` data?

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors?

Comment: Ok so I feel stupid, decided to see what would would happen if I put the script after the comment instead of before the comment and it fixed the problem. No idea why I never thought to do that before.

Comment: It looks obvious now, since the first iteration ran before the document was ready. If you place the javascript above html. That’s the only reason I can see from this. I myself many times forget these basic things too... :)

Comment: The source order should have been a clue for me. The only other issue that's come up is when you click through to the page from the JComments Latest module the url isn't letting the videos load, none of them. Adding the extra '#comment-43' to the end of the link kills the script to load the videos so the whole page is dead. I removed the link for now, not sure if I will bring this up and this question is answered, might see what I can do first.

Comment: @Mythic -  You could start a new question with that, why not? Link back this one as the base of that new question. I also forgot that from the javascript, the document ready function is missing as the first line of the function. If it was there it does not matter if the javascript is below or above the html. So that was the basic problem here. Either way the javascript has to start only when the document is ready (loaded fully) in this case.

Comment: @Zollie What is the line I'm missing? Reading that got me wondering if that might be why the Latest link won't use the script. The html and css both show up,just no image or iframe from the script.

Comment: @Mythic --  In plain javascript the function should start with for example: window.onload = function(){........// here the whole function....}; This would mean that the whole function fires when the whole page is loaded fully. In jQuery you can see many times the same thing: $('document').ready(function(){});

Comment: But i do not think that this is the cause of your new problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script after the html instead of before (in /components/com_jcomments/tpl/default/tpl_comment.php).

If only half of the preview images show up and the rest are stock youtube images, change the image source in the javascript to hqdefault.jpg (instead of sddefault.jpg from code source).

An option to load content on click for bootstrap collapse would have been a better solution in my case, but as far as I can see it is not available.

Here's the css used if anyone wants to keep their videos around 400px wide, it's a little different than the source.

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.youtube {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.youtube img {
    width: 100%;
    top: -16.82%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.youtube .play-button {
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba( 0,0,0,0.6 );
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.youtube .play-button:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 26.0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
.youtube img,
.youtube .play-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.youtube img,
.youtube iframe,
.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
    position: absolute;
}
.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 );
}
.youtube iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```