# Lazy loading script doesn't run after AJAX load

Tags: extensions, javascript

Issue related to

[Video lazy loading skipping first video in every list](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/video-lazy-loading-skipping-first-video-in-every-list)

The css shows up with a black box and the arrow, but script doesn't seem to run after ajax load from pagination, and also when clicking through from JComments Latest link, which adds **#comment-43** to the end of the link to target a specific comment (just picked 43 at random).

Tried adding the script multiple places, putting onload type events in div tag, onhashchange, separating the function and calling it from different places, just doesn't want to load after those 2 cases. Click through direct url to page Page 1 will load preview images, then you click page 2 and no preview/video, back to 1 and no preview/video.

Not familiar with ajax, there are a couple of ajax files in the component directory, could I possibly add something to them?

2 files from **components/com_jcomments/libraries/joomlatune**

ajax.js & ajax.php, here is ajax.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Simple AJAX library (based on code XAJAX library - http://www.xajaxproject.org)
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @package JoomlaTune.Framework
 * @author Sergey M. Litvinov (smart@joomlatune.ru)
 * @copyright (C) 2006-2013 by Sergey M. Litvinov (http://www.joomlatune.ru)
 * @license GNU/GPL: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Check for double include
if (!defined ('JOOMLATUNE_AJAX'))
{
    define ('JOOMLATUNE_AJAX', 1);

    class JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse
    {
        var $aCommands;
        var $xml;
        var $sEncoding;

        function JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse($sEncoding='utf-8')
        {
            $this->aCommands = array();
            $this->sEncoding = $sEncoding;
        }

        function addCommand($aAttributes, $mData)
        {
            $aAttributes['d'] = $mData;
            $this->aCommands[] = $aAttributes;
        }

        function addAssign($sTarget,$sAttribute,$sData)
        {
            $scripts = array();
            // small hack to auto execute JavaScript code returned through ajax
            if (preg_match('/\<script/', $sData)) {
                $regexp = '/<script[^>]+>(.*?)<\/script>/ism';
                $matches = array();
                preg_match_all($regexp, $sData, $matches);

                for ($i = 0, $n = count($matches[0]); $i < $n; $i++) {
                    if ($matches[1][$i] != '') {
                        $sData = str_replace($matches[0][$i], '', $sData);
                        $scripts[] = trim(preg_replace(array('#^<!--#ism', '#\/\/-->$#ism'), '', $matches[1][$i]));
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->addCommand(array('n'=>'as','t'=>$sTarget,'p'=>$sAttribute),$sData);

            if (count($scripts)) {
                foreach ($scripts as $script) {
                    $this->addCommand(array('n'=>'js'),$script);
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }

        function addScript($sJS)
        {
            $sJS = str_replace("\n", '\n', $sJS);
            $sJS = str_replace("\r", '', $sJS);
            $this->addCommand(array('n'=>'js'),$sJS);
            return $this;
        }

        function addAlert($sMsg)
        {
            $this->addCommand(array('n'=>'al'),$sMsg);
            return $this;
        }

        function getOutput()
        {
            $output = '';
            if (is_array($this->aCommands)) {
                $output = JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse::php2js($this->aCommands);
            }
            if (trim($this->sEncoding)) {
                @header('content-type: text/plain; charset="'.$this->sEncoding.'"');
            }
            return $output;
        }

        /**
        * This function taken from JsHttpRequest library
        * JsHttpRequest: PHP backend for JavaScript DHTML loader.
        * (C) Dmitry Koterov, http://en.dklab.ru
        *
        * Convert a PHP scalar, array or hash to JS scalar/array/hash. This function is
        * an analog of json_encode(), but it can work with a non-UTF8 input and does not
        * analyze the passed data. Output format must be fully JSON compatible.
        *
        * @param mixed $a   Any structure to convert to JS.
        * @return string    JavaScript equivalent structure.
        */
        function php2js($a=false)
        {
            if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
            if ($a === false) return 'false';
            if ($a === true) return 'true';
            if (is_scalar($a)) {
                if (is_float($a)) {
                    $a = str_replace(",", ".", strval($a));
                }
                // All scalars are converted to strings to avoid indeterminism.
                // PHP's "1" and 1 are equal for all PHP operators, but
                // JS's "1" and 1 are not. So if we pass "1" or 1 from the PHP backend,
                // we should get the same result in the JS frontend (string).
                // Character replacements for JSON.
                static $jsonReplaces = array(
                array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'),
                array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"')
                );
                return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
            }
            $isList = true;
            for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a)) {
                if (key($a) !== $i) {
                    $isList = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $result = array();
            if ($isList) {
                foreach ($a as $v) {
                    $result[] = JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse::php2js($v);
                }
                return '[ ' . join(', ', $result) . ' ]';
            } else {
                foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
                    $k = JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse::php2js($k);
                    $v = JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse::php2js($v);
                    $result[] = $k . ': ' . $v;
                }
                return '{ ' . join(', ', $result) . ' }';
            }
        }
    }

    class JoomlaTuneAjax
    {
        var $aFunctions;
        var $aObjects;
        var $aFunctionRequestTypes;
        var $sRequestURI;
        var $sEncoding;

        function JoomlaTuneAjax($sRequestURI="",$sEncoding='utf-8')
        {
            $this->aFunctions = array();
            $this->aFunctionRequestTypes = array();
            $this->aObjects = array();
            $this->aFunctionIncludeFiles = array();
            $this->sRequestURI = $sRequestURI;
            if ($this->sRequestURI == "") {
                $this->sRequestURI = $this->_detectURI();
            }
            $this->setCharEncoding($sEncoding);
        }

        function setCharEncoding($sEncoding)
        {
            $this->sEncoding = $sEncoding;
        }

        function registerFunction($mFunction,$sRequestType=1)
        {
            if (is_array($mFunction)) {
                $this->aFunctions[$mFunction[0]] = 1;
                $this->aFunctionRequestTypes[$mFunction[0]] = $sRequestType;
                $this->aObjects[$mFunction[0]] = array_slice($mFunction, 1);
            } else {
                $this->aFunctions[$mFunction] = 1;
                $this->aFunctionRequestTypes[$mFunction] = $sRequestType;
            }
        }

        function processRequest()
        {
            return $this->processRequests();
        }

        function _isObjectCallback($sFunction)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($sFunction, $this->aObjects)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        function _callFunction($sFunction, $aArgs)
        {
            if ($this->_isObjectCallback($sFunction)) {
                $mReturn = call_user_func_array($this->aObjects[$sFunction], $aArgs);
            } else if (array_key_exists($sFunction, $this->aFunctions)) {
                $mReturn = call_user_func_array($sFunction, $aArgs);
            }
            return $mReturn;
        }

        function processRequests()
        {
            $sFunctionName = $_REQUEST["jtxf"];
            $aArgs = isset($_REQUEST["jtxa"]) ? $_REQUEST["jtxa"] : array();

            if (!array_key_exists($sFunctionName, $this->aFunctions)) {
                $oResponse = new JoomlaTuneAjaxResponse();
                $oResponse->addAlert("Unknown Function $sFunctionName.");
            } else {
                $oResponse = $this->_callFunction($sFunctionName, $aArgs);
            }
            @header('content-type: text/plain; charset="'.$this->sEncoding.'"');
            print $oResponse->getOutput();
            exit();
        }

        function _detectURI() {
            $aURL = array();

            // Try to get the request URL
            if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace(array('"',"'",'<','>'), array('%22','%27','%3C','%3E'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $aURL = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            }

            // Fill in the empty values
            if (empty($aURL['scheme'])) {
                if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_SCHEME'])) {
                    $aURL['scheme'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_SCHEME'];
                } else {
                    $aURL['scheme'] = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off') ? 'https' : 'http';
                }
            }

            if (empty($aURL['host'])) {
                if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
                    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'], ':') > 0) {
                        list($aURL['host'], $aURL['port']) = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']);
                    } else {
                        $aURL['host'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
                    }
                } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
                    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ':') > 0) {
                        list($aURL['host'], $aURL['port']) = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
                    } else {
                        $aURL['host'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                    }
                } else if (!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
                    $aURL['host'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
                } else {
                    print "Error: ajax failed to automatically identify your Request URI.";
                    print "Please set the Request URI explicitly when you instantiate the jtajax object.";
                    exit();
                }
            }

            if (empty($aURL['port']) && !empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])) {
                $aURL['port'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
            }

            if (empty($aURL['path'])) {
                if (!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
                    $sPath = parse_url($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
                } else {
                    $sPath = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                }
                $aURL['path'] = str_replace(array('"',"'",'<','>'), array('%22','%27','%3C','%3E'), $sPath['path']);
                unset($sPath);
            }

            if (!empty($aURL['query'])) {
                $aURL['query'] = '?'.$aURL['query'];
            }

            // Build the URL: Start with scheme, user and pass
            $sURL = $aURL['scheme'].'://';
            if (!empty($aURL['user'])) {
                $sURL.= $aURL['user'];
                if (!empty($aURL['pass'])) {
                    $sURL.= ':'.$aURL['pass'];
                }
                $sURL.= '@';
            }

            // Add the host
            $sURL.= $aURL['host'];

            // Add the port if needed
            if (!empty($aURL['port']) && (($aURL['scheme'] == 'http' && $aURL['port'] != 80) || ($aURL['scheme'] == 'https' && $aURL['port'] != 443))) {
                $sURL.= ':'.$aURL['port'];
            }

            // Add the path and the query string
            $sURL.= $aURL['path'].@$aURL['query'];

            // Clean up
            unset($aURL);
            return $sURL;
        }
    }
} // end of double include check
```

I can post ajax.js, just not sure how much space there is here and how much I can post. Try here starting on line 4: https://ideone.com/8df01C

Other file is components/jcomments/jcomments.ajax.php 
Try it here starting on line4: https://ideone.com/16szL9

The pagination code is added to **component/com_jcomments/jcomments.php**

```
public static function getCommentsTree($object_id, $object_group = 'com_content', $page = 0)
    {
        $object_id = (int)$object_id;
        $object_group = trim($object_group);

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $acl = JCommentsFactory::getACL();
        $config = JCommentsFactory::getConfig();

                $comments_per_page = $config->getInt('comments_per_page');
                $limitstart = 0;

        $total = JComments::getCommentsCount($object_id, $object_group, 'c.level = 0');

        if ($acl->canComment() == 0 && $total == 0) {
            return '';
        }

        if ($total > 0) {
            $options = array();
                        $options['pagination'] = 'tree';
            $options['object_id'] = $object_id;
            $options['object_group'] = $object_group;
            $options['published'] = $acl->canPublish() || $acl->canPublishForObject($object_id, $object_group) ? null : 1;
            $options['votes'] = $config->getInt('enable_voting');

            if ($comments_per_page > 0) {
                $page = (int)$page;

                require_once(JCOMMENTS_HELPERS . '/pagination.php');
                $pagination = new JCommentsPagination($object_id, $object_group);
                $pagination->setCurrentPage($page);
                                $pagination->setCommentsCount($total);

                $total_pages = $pagination->getTotalPages();
                $this_page = $pagination->getCurrentPage();
                $limitstart = $pagination->getLimitStart();
                $comments_per_page = $pagination->getCommentsPerPage();

                $options['limit'] = $comments_per_page;
                $options['limitStart'] = $limitstart;
            }

            $rows = JCommentsModel::getCommentsList($options);

        } else {
            $rows = array();
        }

        $tmpl = JCommentsFactory::getTemplate($object_id, $object_group);
        $tmpl->load('tpl_tree');
        $tmpl->load('tpl_comment');

        if (count($rows)) {

            $isLocked = ($config->getInt('comments_locked', 0) == 1);

            $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-refresh', intval(!$isLocked));
            $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-rss', intval($config->getInt('enable_rss') && !$isLocked));
            $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-can-subscribe', intval($user->id && $acl->check('enable_subscribe') && !$isLocked));
            $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-count', count($rows));
                        $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-bottom', 1);

            if ($user->id && $acl->check('enable_subscribe')) {
                require_once(JCOMMENTS_SITE . '/jcomments.subscription.php');
                $manager = JCommentsSubscriptionManager::getInstance();
                $isSubscribed = $manager->isSubscribed($object_id, $object_group, $user->id);
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-user-subscribed', $isSubscribed);
            }

            $i = 1;

            JCommentsEventHelper::trigger('onJCommentsCommentsPrepare', array(&$rows));

            if ($acl->check('enable_gravatar')) {
                JCommentsEventHelper::trigger('onPrepareAvatars', array(&$rows));
            }

            require_once(JCOMMENTS_LIBRARIES . '/joomlatune/tree.php');

            $tree = new JoomlaTuneTree($rows);
            $items = $tree->get();

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                // run autocensor, replace quotes, smilies and other pre-view processing
                JComments::prepareComment($row);

                // setup toolbar
                if (!$acl->canModerate($row)) {
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comments-panel-visible', 0);
                } else {
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comments-panel-visible', 1);
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-edit', $acl->canEdit($row));
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-delete', $acl->canDelete($row));
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-publish', $acl->canPublish($row));
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-ip', $acl->canViewIP($row));
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-ban', $acl->canBan($row));
                }

                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comment-show-vote', $config->getInt('enable_voting'));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comment-show-email', $acl->canViewEmail($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comment-show-homepage', $acl->canViewHomepage($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comment-show-title', $config->getInt('comment_title'));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-vote', $acl->canVote($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-quote', $acl->canQuote($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-reply', $acl->canReply($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'button-report', $acl->canReport($row));
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'avatar', $acl->check('enable_gravatar') && !$row->deleted);

                if (isset($items[$row->id])) {
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_comment', 'comment-number', '');
                    $tmpl->addObject('tpl_comment', 'comment', $row);
                    $items[$row->id]->html = $tmpl->renderTemplate('tpl_comment');
                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $tmpl->addObject('tpl_tree', 'comments-items', $items);

            // build page navigation
            if (($comments_per_page > 0) && ($total_pages > 1)) {
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-first', 1);
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-total', $total_pages);
                $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-active', $this_page);

                $pagination = $config->get('comments_pagination');

                // show top pagination
                if (($pagination == 'both') || ($pagination == 'top')) {
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-top', 1);
                }

                // show bottom pagination
                if (($pagination == 'both') || ($pagination == 'bottom')) {
                    $tmpl->addVar('tpl_tree', 'comments-nav-bottom', 1);
                }
            }
            unset($rows);
        }

        return $tmpl->renderTemplate('tpl_tree');
    }
```

and **component/com_jcomments/tpl/default/tpl_tree.php**

```
  function getNavigation() {
    if ($this->getVar('comments-nav-top') == 1 
    ||  $this->getVar('comments-nav-bottom') == 1) {
      $active_page = $this->getVar('comments-nav-active', 1);
      $first_page = $this->getVar('comments-nav-first', 0);
      $total_page = $this->getVar('comments-nav-total', 0);

      if ($first_page != 0 && $total_page != 0) {
      $object_id = $this->getVar('comment-object_id');
      $object_group = $this->getVar('comment-object_group');

      $content = '';

        // number of visible pages
        $pp = 14;

        $fp = $active_page - $pp/2;
        if ($fp <= 0) {
        $fp = 1;
        }

        $lp = $fp + $pp;
        if ($lp > $total_page) {
        $lp = $total_page;
        }

        if ($lp - $fp < $pp && $pp < $total_page) {
        $fp = $lp - $pp;
        }

        if ($fp > 1) {
        $content .= '<span onclick="jcomments.showPage('.$object_id.', \''.$object_group.'\', '.($active_page-1).');" class="page" onmouseover="this.className=\'hoverpage\';" onmouseout="this.className=\'page\';" >&laquo;</span>';
        }

        for ($i=$fp; $i <= $lp; $i++) {
          if ($i == $active_page) {
          $content .= '<span class="activepage"><b>'.$i.'</b></span>';
          } else {
          $content .= '<span onclick="jcomments.showPage('.$object_id.', \''.$object_group.'\', '.$i.');" class="page" onmouseover="this.className=\'hoverpage\';" onmouseout="this.className=\'page\';" >'.$i.'</span>';
          }
        }

        if ($lp < $total_page) {
          $content .= '<span onclick="jcomments.showPage('.$object_id.', \''.$object_group.'\', '.($lp+1).');" class="page" onmouseover="this.className=\'hoverpage\';" onmouseout="this.className=\'page\';" >&raquo;</span>';
        }

      return $content;
      }
    }
        return '';
  }
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to paste some of the ajax codes here in the question.

Comment: Before dealing with the ajax, you should check two things which are errors according to the console: 1. jQuery is not defined in .../com_jcomments/js/jcomments-v2.3.js:378:9  - probably you inserted a short jQuery script at the end of this .js file, I suspect that it will not work here this way. Load that short script from somewhere else. 2. A closing curly bracket is missing from your youtube loading jQuery function somewhere (after function body).

Comment: Took care of js file, don't see where curly bracket is missing though. Code is in linked related thread, all look to be there.

Comment: Figure it has to be the ajax, I could be wrong though. The pagination works ok so far for the ones displayed in the separate profile page, loads all videos on every page. Hash isn't that big of a deal from Latest, if you're already on the page and had it loaded it just goes to the comment with video already loaded and working, just not from any other pages, goes to comment but no preview/video in any comments.

Comment: As i see the console does not show any more js error if I load your page. That's good. The original problem is still present?

Comment: Yes, still present.

Comment: @Mythic - it’s a bit harder to follow your project, so I had to read few times what you wrote about and which and where (same would happen with you if you’d read my projects :), but from what I understand from the above, that it looks like as jQuery would not be loaded in every page of yours where the scripts should run or there is a conflict somwhere of javascript libraries. Are you sure that those basic libraries are always loaded on every of your pages and not two times in two versions? I have not checked this on your page (only that your opening page (you linked) is OK)

Comment: If the script, which has to run, loaded, then the above reasons could cause not to run. But your browser console also would show errors, undefined objects, type errors and so on, if the script is loaded and there would be some error. Your copied ajax.js can cause conflict but that would also appear in your console. So I do not see clearly what the problem is there. I did not check that deeply though.

Comment: I was a bit wrong above since as I remeber your script is in plain javascript (not in jquery), so that cannot cause your issue. Something else is the problem...

Comment: Found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552250/how-do-i-execute-a-javascript-after-ajax-load) and a couple others, but can't get the code or the script to combine right, or haven't found where it needs to go yet, or it just isn't what i'm looking for. Not sure which yet.

Comment: Focusing on **components/jcomments/jcomments.ajax.php** showPage and showComment trying variations of the above.Shown here: (https://ideone.com/FLMEj5). The 2nd page won't load, just keeps showing page 1, but the ajax dial comes up and acts like it's loading.... and the script is working afterward. So not sure if the ajax actually kicked in and loaded the previews just won't change the page, or if just the working dial came up and the page stayed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I like your question and a lot of details that you provided. I like people on StackExchange who can ask questions properly, clearly with precise details. This separates the real developers from quite ignorant people. So I like your question, but: honestly it took me quite a while to understand your question. The long, actually from the point of view of your question, irrelevant details of your project can cause a bit confusion about what your question is. It's also true that many times happen with me the same, that I do not know how to ask a question about my issue. So the right question usually embrace the answer itself somewhere. :)

> Your question simply: **how to fire an** javascript or jquery **script** after an ajax call. Or more precisely, **after an ajax call is completed.** **Any ajax call**. :) This is that simple now.

Of course this was a question of millions of developers before you so jQuery has a solution for this.

You have to use the jQuery **`.ajaxComplete()`** function. This function ignites when **any ajax request** is finished on a page. Since an ajax call is also a Global ajax event when completed. These events are triggered on the document, calling any handlers which may be listening.

Thus, my suggestion is, since you already have a well working javascript script to load the youtube videos' sources. Then you should just wrap that or call that with the jQuery **.ajaxComplete()** function, something like this:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    videoListLoad();
});

function videoListLoad () {

    var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );

    for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {

        var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/hqdefault.jpg";

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = source;
        image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
            youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
        }( i ) );

        youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

            var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
            iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
            iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
            iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );

            this.innerHTML = "";
            this.appendChild( iframe );
        } );
    }
}
```

Create and load this additional script on your page (in the head for example) and try this and give me some feedback (Of course I have not tried this on your page). Do not touch your original script on your site, you just have to leave that there too. So you will have two similar scripts, one for normal page load and one for ajax events like pagination. Just to make sure it is clear for you.

More info on this jQuery function is here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

You initial javascript function could be bound other way like:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){ ...// your function... });
```

But I just wanted to give you an example which you can use on your page. I hope this will solve your issue.

(Of course, this can starts other new questions later, for example: how to unbind this function from other irrelevant ajax requests on the page but that's the question of another day)

**UPDATE**

Now, there is a possibility that the above will not work (if the ajax call is not jQuery ajax), however sounds very good, then the next valuable approach would be to build the video source loading .js function (script) in the ajax.js function which has to fire this function this way. So I copy here the edited ajax.js file and please use this instead of your file (keep the original ajax.js file though!! You can just rename it old-ajax.js or something.)

I just built in the videoloading function after the ajax response is processed. So you will see if it's successful this way.

```
/* based on xajax Javascript library (http://www.xajaxproject.org) */
if (!window.jtajax) {

    function jtAJAX()
    {
        this.options = {url: '',type: 'post',nocache: true,data: ''};

        this.$ = function(id) {if(!id){return null;}var o=document.getElementById(id);if(!o&&document.all){o=document.all[id];}return o;};
        this.extend = function(o, e){for(var k in (e||{}))o[k]=e[k];return o;};
        this.encode = function(t){return encodeURIComponent(t);};
        this.setup = function(options) {this.options = this.extend(this.options, options);};

        this.xhr = function()
        {
            var xhr = null;
            if ('undefined' != typeof XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (!xhr && 'undefined' != typeof ActiveXObject) {
                var msxmlhttp = new Array('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0','Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0','Msxml2.XMLHTTP','Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                for (var i=0;i<msxmlhttp.length;i++){try{xhr=new ActiveXObject(msxmlhttp[i]);}catch(e){xhr=null;}}
            }
            return xhr;
        };

        this.form2query = function(sId)
        {
            var frm = this.$(sId);
            if (frm && frm.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'FORM') {
                var e = frm.elements, query = [];
                for (var i=0; i < e.length; i++) {
                    var name = e[i].name;
                    if (!name) continue;
                    if (e[i].type && ('radio' == e[i].type || 'checkbox' == e[i].type) && false === e[i].checked) continue;
                    if ('select-multiple' == e[i].type) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < e[i].length; j++) {
                            if (true === e[i].options[j].selected)
                                query.push(name+"="+this.encode(e[i].options[j].value));
                        }
                    } else { query.push(name+"="+this.encode(e[i].value));
                    }
                }
                return query.join('&');
            }
            return '';
        };

        this.startLoading = function(){};
        this.finishLoading = function(){};

        this.ajax = function(options)
        {
            var xhr = this.xhr();
            if (!xhr) return false;
            var o = this.extend(this.options, options);
            var url = o.url, jtx = this;url=url.replace(/&amp;/g,'&');
            var r=url;var h=location.hostname,d,i1,i2;i1=r.indexOf('://');if(i1!=-1){i2=r.indexOf('/',i1+3);if(i2!=-1){d=r.substring(i1+3,i2);if(d!=h){if(location.port!=''){h=h+':'+location.port;}r=r.replace(d,h);url=r;}}}

            if ('get' == o.type) {
                if (true === o.nocache) {
                    var ts=new Date().getTime();
                    url += (url.indexOf("?")==-1 ? '?' : '&') + '_jtxr_' + ts;
                }
                if (o.data) {
                    url += (url.indexOf("?")==-1 ? '?' : '&') + o.data;
                    o.data = null;
                }
            }

            xhr.open(o.type.toUpperCase(), url, true);

            if ('post' == o.type)
                try {xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");}catch(e){}
            if (true === o.nocache)
                xhr.setRequestHeader('If-Modified-Since', 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
                jtx.finishLoading();
                if (xhr.status==200) {
                    jtx.processResponse(xhr.responseText);
                }
                delete xhr;
                xhr = null;
            };
            try {
                jtx.startLoading();
                xhr.send(o.data);
            } catch(e) { jtx.finishLoading(); }

            delete jtx;
            delete xhr;
            delete o;
            return true;
        };

        this.call = function(sFunction, aArgs, sType, sForm)
        {
            var params = 'jtxf=' + this.encode(sFunction);
            if (aArgs) {
                for (var i=0;i<aArgs.length;i++) {
                    params += '&jtxa[]=' + this.encode(aArgs[i]);
                }
            } else if (sForm) {
                params += '&' + this.form2query(sForm);
            }

            this.ajax({type: sType, data: params});
            return true;
        };

        this.processResponse = function(sText)
        {
            if(sText==='') return false;
            if(sText.substring(0,3)!='[ {'){var idx=sText.indexOf('[ {');sText=sText.substr(idx);}
            var result;try {result=eval(sText);}catch(e){}
            if ('undefined' == typeof result) {return false;}

            var cmd, id, property, data, obj = null;

            for (var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                cmd         = result[i]['n'];
                id      = result[i]['t'];
                property    = result[i]['p'];
                data        = result[i]['d'];
                obj         = this.$(id);

                switch(cmd) {
                    case 'as': if(obj){eval("obj."+property+"=data;");} break;
                    case 'al': if(data){alert(data);} break;
                    case 'js': if(data){eval(data);} break;
                    default: this.error('Unknown command: ' + cmd);break;
                }
            }

            delete result;
            delete cmd;
            delete id;
            delete property;
            delete data;
            delete obj;
            this.videoListLoad();
            return true;
        };

        this.error = function(){};

        this.videoListLoad = function()
        {

            var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );

            for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {

                var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/hqdefault.jpg";

                var image = new Image();
                image.src = source;
                image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
                    youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
                }( i ) );

                youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

                    var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
                    iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
                    iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
                    iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );

                    this.innerHTML = "";
                    this.appendChild( iframe );
                } );
            }

        };

    }

    var jtajax = new jtAJAX();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zollie. Going to have to play around with it for a bit, doesn't seem to be working anyplace I put it.

Comment: @Mythic -  then I'll update my answer on this a bit later. I see the script on your page now.

Comment: @Mythic - I updated my answer, please try that new edited ajax.js file instead of the original file. Keep me posted about the results.

Comment: Works good now Zollie. Thank you very much, I never would have been able to incorporate that script there. It also even works with the hashtag links from Latest Comments. Very nice. First glances anyway, will post back if any other hiccups pop up.

Comment: @Mythic - Excellent! I’m glad that finally it’s running well.

Comment: Just a heads up on this, it works great for desktop, but does not work for a couple of mobile versions of firefox and chrome I've tested, same problem as before (hashtag links and pagination kills the script). Not all versions though, some tested on different phones worked fine.

Comment: @Mythic - yes, I’ve seen the problem on my tablet. I’ll check that why and the fix on that if there is.

Comment: @Mythic - however, I tried to check this issue on your page and went to your page with my iPad chrome this morning, and it works without any problem. (I emptied my browser cache).

Comment: @Mythic - it works on my safari browser too.

Comment: @Mythic - and I can confirm that it works on my samsung note9 chrome too. so I cannot reproduce and check the problem anywhere.

Comment: same here on other versions. The phone it didn't work on is a ZTE phone (track phone i think), I say as long as the number of mobile versions is small this isn't much of a problem and will leave as is, if those users ask there are ways they can avoid those links.

Comment: The only problem I see for them is if they try to go past page 1, then all the videos are dead after that, unless they sort through history. Hopefully that one phone isn't the only device they have. The load time (1.16 seconds - pingdom) and size (still under 1 mb - 999.5kb - pingdom) with 34 videos on the page is amazing compared to before.

Comment: @Mythic - I'm not sure if they have javascript on their phone browser on in their browser settings.. That can cause this problem for them.